# Why calling modal.show() in php doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, php, semantic-ui, modalviewcontroller

I want to show modal when user email is not on database. 
I write `$('.ui.basic.modal').modal('show');` in 
php `$echo`. 
It doesn't show. 
In semantic UI modal example, modal shows on Run Code Button click.
Semantic-UI Example Link
https://semantic-ui.com/modules/modal.html

I'm using semantic UI modal.

```
//PHP Code
if(!result)
{
 echo "<script>$('.ui.basic.modal').modal('show');</script>";
}
//MyModal
<div class="ui basic modal">
    <div class="ui icon header">
        <i class="frown outline icon"></i>
        Cannot find your email?
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>You are still on waiting list.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify and verify if your PHP code is actually echoing your script tag? And can you also verify that your code is loaded with Semantic UI's scripts?

Comment: Semantic UI's scripts is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.ui.basic.modal` element does not exists when your javascript code is executed.

You have to execute the js code after the modal creation, and to use document.ready function or equivalent.

Try

```php
<?php
if(!$result){
?>
    <div class="ui basic modal">
        <div class="ui icon header">
            <i class="frown outline icon"></i>
            Cannot find your email?
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>You are still on waiting list.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('.ui.basic.modal').modal('show');
    });
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

This suppose that jQuery and Semantic-ui javascript sources are loaded.

Comment: It doesn't work.
It show only text and then page refresh.

Comment: So you have another problem elsewhere, what is the code that requests this page?
What does the javascript console of your browser say?